# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace' : When running yfinance (Yahoo Finance) to read stock data i am getting error for a list of stocks

Tags: python, yfinance

I am running this code to get stock data for a list of stocks and getting an error

```
import yfinance as yf
start = datetime.datetime(2018,5,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,8,31)
yfdata = yf.download(stocks, start = start, end = end)
print(yfdata.head(5))
```

The error we are getting is:"    tickers, (list, set, tuple)) else tickers.replace(',', ' ').split()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Any ideas?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to yf.download is supposed to be a string with a list of ticker symbols.  It looks like you are passing a numpy array.